# return new FileStreamResult write Stream content to View instead downloading as file

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 I am trying a simple code to generate a Stream file download OnPost

```
public IActionResult OnPostDwonloadFile()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World"));
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"))
        {
            FileDownloadName = "test.txt"
        };
    }
```

The Razor Page View code:

```
<form method="post"
  asp-page-handler="DwonloadFile"
  data-ajax="true"
  data-ajax-method="POST"
  data-ajax-begin="AjaxOnBegin"
  data-ajax-complete="AjaxOnComplete"
  data-ajax-failure="failed"
  data-ajax-update="#div_BusyIndicator">

<div id="div_BusyIndicator"></div>

<button type="submit" style="width: 200pt;" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-3">test</button>
```

Problem is that `return new FileStreamResult` returns content that is displayed on the Page/View instead of downloading as text.txt.

How to solve this please?

Comment: If you want to download a file, you have to trigger a download, not render it in a view. How do you currently call this action, and what have you tried to make it a download?

Comment: I have updated my code with the view HTML

Comment: Are you trying to download file through Ajax? Why not do form post directly to download it?

Comment: I need this Ajax code so deleting it is not an option.